# Vbox mouse cursor disappear only in text editor of a guest OS

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, mouse, guest-additions

The problem is following: Suddenly the edit text mouse cursor disappear in guest OS text editors and text fields. Instead of `Text Select` cursor only few pixels are visible.

Issue related to windows guests (I had this on Win7-64 and Win2016-64) and windows host (win10-64). Update of vbox, guest additions, extension packs - did not help.
Any ideas how to fix?
Vbox version so far: 5.2.20 r125813 (Qt5.6.2) GA and EP enabled.

Comment: this is not a duplicate. because this problem related only to text editors

Comment: Isn't it possible it's [this feature](https://superuser.com/questions/928839/what-does-the-hide-pointer-while-typing-feature-actually-do) enabled?

Comment: This option does not affect anything